# List Manipulation on Grouping and Shifting

Tags: list-manipulation

I have an input

```
list = {a,b,c,d,e,f},
```

I would like to get this output

```
{{a,b},{b,c},{c,d},{d,e},{e,f}}
```

What is the easiest way to do it in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Look up `Partition[]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
list = {a, b, c, d, e, f};
Partition[list, 2, 1]

(*{{a, b}, {b, c}, {c, d}, {d, e}, {e, f}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

$\ldots$ and then there is:

```
ClearAll[partition];
partition[ { a___List, s1_Symbol, s2_Symbol, b__Symbol } ] := partition[

   { a, {s1, s2}, s2, b } 

]
partition[ {a___List, s1_Symbol, s2_Symbol }] := { a, {s1, s2 } }

partition[ {a, b, c, d, e, f} ]
```

> {{a, b}, {b, c}, {c, d}, {d, e}, {e, f}}

Comment: Certainly `Partition[ ]` is easiest, but is it *fun*? :) Imagine *Mathematica 25* has just come out with the new feature `SolveProblem[ probEnt_, Method -> "StraightForward" ]`-- a horror.

Comment: `SolveProblem[probEnt_, "MindReader" -> True]` would be much more useful, in that case.

Comment: @J. M. Sorry, I had forgotten to mention that in *Mathematica 25* `"MindReading" -> True` is a global option for the FrontEnd. :)

Comment: @gwr I'm already reusing your v25 code in another thread :-) I reckon, `SolveProblem[s_String]` will just internally call `ServiceConnect["M.SE"]`. `Timing` will be horrific, and `RepeatedTiming` will earn bans, but it'll make the ultimate natural language parser.